# Problem trying to lock framerate at 60 FPS

Tags: c++, sdl, frame-rate

I've written a simple class to limit the framerate of my current project.
But it does not work as it should. Here is the code:

```
void FpsCounter::Process()
{
    deltaTime = static_cast<double>(frameTimer.GetMsecs());
    waitTime = 1000.0/fpsLimit - deltaTime;
    frameTimer.Reset();

    if(waitTime <= 0)
    {
        std::cout << "error, waittime: " << waitTime << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        SDL_Delay(static_cast<Uint32>(waitTime));
    }

    if(deltaTime == 0)
    {
        currFps = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        currFps = 1000/deltaTime;
    }

    std::cout << "--Timings--" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Delta: \t" << deltaTime << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Delay: \t" << waitTime << std::endl;
    std::cout << "FPS: \t" << currFps << std::endl;
    std::cout << "--       --" << std::endl;
}

Timer::Timer()
{
    startMsecs = 0;
}

Timer::~Timer()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

void Timer::Start()
{
    started = true;
    paused = false;
    Reset();
}

void Timer::Pause()
{
    if(started && !paused)
    {
        paused = true;

        pausedMsecs = SDL_GetTicks() - startMsecs;
    }
}

void Timer::Resume()
{
    if(paused)
    {
        paused = false;

        startMsecs = SDL_GetTicks() - pausedMsecs;

        pausedMsecs = 0;
    }
}

int Timer::GetMsecs()
{
    if(started)
    {
        if(paused)
        {
            return pausedMsecs;
        }
        else
        {
            return SDL_GetTicks() - startMsecs;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void Timer::Reset()
{
    startMsecs = SDL_GetTicks();
}
```

The "FpsCounter::Process()" Method is called everytime at the end of my gameloop.

I've got the problem that the loop is correctly delayed only every second frame, so it runs one frame delayed at 60 FPS and the next without delay at over 1000 fps.

I am searching the error quite a while now, but I do not find it.

I hope somebody can point me in the right direction.

Comment: What is the output from your cout calls when this happens?

Comment: Just v-sync, everthing else does not make much sense for the game thread

Comment: @MaikSemder Enabling VSync will lock the frame rate to the monitor refresh rate which may not always be 60Hz (it could be 75 or even 120) which will affect gameplay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reset the timer **after** you have waited. Otherwise, the wait time will be part of the duration of the next frame and the algorithm will think it is running slowly.

Answer (score 2):

This wrong on many levels. The code behaves like it does because you reset the timer before you have finished waiting for the correct time for the current frame to come. If you moved the reset to after the wait block it should work like you have planned.

This is however still a very poor and inexact time control as it does not correct slight lapses of one frame in the next. What you really need is to have game logic running at a fixed rate and rendering running as fast as possible, though possibly with v-sync on so that it is limited to the screen update rate.

Your game loop should look something like this: (Edited, pausing will probably work better in the new version.)

```
double nextFrame = static_cast<double>SDL_GetTicks();
while(true){
    while(nextFrame > static_cast<double>SDL_GetTicks()){
        render();
    }
    nextFrame += 1000.0 / logicrate;
    if(!paused)
        gameLogic();
}
```

Alternate version that caps the frame rate at the logic rate:

```
double nextFrame = static_cast<double>SDL_GetTicks();
while(true){
    if(nextFrame > static_cast<double>SDL_GetTicks()){
        render();
    }
    if(!paused)
        gameLogic();
    delay = static_cast<Uint32> (nextFrame - static_cast<double>SDL_GetTicks());
    if(delay > 0){
        SDL_Delay(delay);
    }
    nextFrame += 1000.0 / logicrate;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why it is bad to limit the framerate by wait a calculated time at the end of every loop. Can you explain that a little bit more? Also I have in mind to port my game to android, so I think sleeping a few microseconds where it is possible should be also positive for battery life.

Comment: @shad0w: If you try to limit the frame rate to 60 fps, and you start taking longer than 1/60 s to render, then your frame rate will start to be *divided* by the number of frames it takes to render the scene: 30fps, 20fps, 15fps, and so on. Whereas, if you render/update based on how fast the game is actually running, the frame rate degrades much more gracefully. You do this by recording the time it takes to render the scene (`dt`), then advancing the scene by that amount, e.g., `position += velocity * dt`.

Comment: I know that, but I think my game wont become so complex that it will take more time to render then 1/60 sec. At least I hope so. I also tried time based movement of, but that method ads a lots of complexity for me, so I would like to avoid that, as far as it is possible.

Comment: You can never guarantee that your game wont run at less than 1/60th of a second, even on PCs that are faster than you require. Simply because a computer can do a lot of things while running the game, for example start the virus scanner or a backup procedure. These can cause notable stutter for a few seconds while your game is trying to catch up while one based on deltaTime never has to.

Comment: Ok, I will consider that option. @eBusiness: Maybe I did not understand you correctly, but how does render more often than update makes senses? I think when the game doesn't get updated, there is nothing new to render.

Comment: Moreover I think that time-based movement could cause troble with my collision detection.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to render if the frame hasn't changed, or the screen hasn't been refreshed. But you'd actually want to delegate the job of deciding how often to update to the video card, you do that by having v-sync enabled, then the video card will if possible render once for each screen update if there is time for it, any alternate method risks being out of sync and thus causing tearing or framedrops. I have added a version that doesn't allow the rendering rate to exceed the game logic update rate.

Comment: delay is actually a Unsigned int 32, it makes no sence to compare it to 0

Answer (score 0):

This problem have already been discussed here : [Make the game run 60 fps in Irrlicht Engine](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/25354/make-the-game-run-60-fps-in-irrlicht-engine/)

(initial question is for iirlicht engine but what have been said there also applied to other environments)

Comment: This should be a comment on the main question.

Answer (score 0):

Mine is something like this...

```
     timer.Update();

     static float frameTime = 0.0f;
     static int frames = 0;
     frameTime += timer.DeltaTime();
     frames++;

     while(frameTime >= kTimeStep)
     {
        (object->*callback)(frameTime);
        frames = 0;
        frameTime -= kTimeStep;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something such as 3 stages waiting:

```
        m_tickEnd = m_timer.Mark() * 1000.0; // converting seconds to milliseconds
    
    // Doing all three stages of waiting would safe CPU usage from 30% to less than 10% for a 8 cores PC
    // 1. sleep
    while (m_ticksPerFrame - m_tickEnd > 6)
    {
        // sleep until has roughly +/- 1 millisecond accuracy
        std::this_thread::sleep_until(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + std::chrono::milliseconds{ 5 });
        m_tickEnd = m_timer.Mark() * 1000.0;
    }
    while (m_ticksPerFrame - m_tickEnd > 4)
    {
        // sleep until has roughly +/- 1 millisecond accuracy
        std::this_thread::sleep_until(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + std::chrono::milliseconds{ 3 });
        m_tickEnd = m_timer.Mark() * 1000.0;
    }
    while (m_ticksPerFrame - m_tickEnd > 2)
    {
        // sleep until has roughly +/- 1 millisecond accuracy
        std::this_thread::sleep_until(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + std::chrono::milliseconds{ 1 });
        m_tickEnd = m_timer.Mark() * 1000.0;
    }

    // 2. yield
    while (m_tickEnd < m_ticksPerFrame * .99)
    {
        // yield has roughly +/- 30 microsecond accuracy, it could work as a more accurate sleep function at fine grain.
        std::this_thread::yield();
        m_tickEnd = m_timer.Mark() * 1000.0; // converting seconds to milliseconds
    }

    // 3. busy wait
    do {
        m_tickEnd = m_timer.Mark() * 1000.0; // converting seconds to milliseconds
    } while (m_tickEnd < m_ticksPerFrame * .9999);
```